# Атрибут курсора description в спецификации database API 2

Tags: python, база-данных

Поясните, каким образом используются атрибуты из [description](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#description). В спецификации этот вопрос не раскрывается

- name
- type_code
- display_size
- internal_size
- precision
- scale
- null_ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственный источник, который я нашёл -- это [драйвер](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.Column) от postgres. Описание:

- name. Имя возвращаемого столбца.
- type_code. OID PostgreSQL столбца. Вы можете использовать системную таблицу pg_type, чтобы получить больше информации о типе. Это значение, используемое Psycopg, чтобы решить, какой тип Python использовать для представления значения.
- display_size.    Предполагается, что это фактическая длина столбца в байтах. Получение этого значения требует больших вычислительных ресурсов, поэтому оно всегда равно None. Изменено в версии 2.8: ранее это значение можно было получить с помощью флага компилятора во встроенном.
- internal_size. Размер в байтах столбца, связанного с этим столбцом на сервере. Установите отрицательное значение для типов переменного размера. См. Также PQfsize.
- precision. Общее количество значащих цифр в столбцах типа NUMERIC. Для других типов нет.
- scale. Подсчет десятичных цифр в дробной части в столбцах типа NUMERIC. Для других типов нет.
- null_ok. Всегда None, так как получить из libpq непросто.

Для postgres есть её ряд параметров. С ними можно ознакомиться по ссылке. Ещё один источник есть [здесь](https://python.su/forum/topic/33563/) и [здесь](https://github.com/Teradata/PyTd/issues/54).